# Why Does My CSS Take Forever To Change Using Wordpress?

Tags: css, hosting

I can't figure out anything. I have search everywhere. I'm updating my CSS and it takes a long time to display the results of the code change. I'm using A Small Orange shared hosting and might go to OVH VPS, so is it because I'm on shared which is delaying it?

THANKS :D

Comment: Regarding moving from ASO to OVH.... I done the same thing. ASO will offer you a lot of technical support whereas OVH offer none. If something goes wrong on your VPS, you're fixing it without OVH support. Only move if you are confident in managing and fixing the VPS.

Comment: @FearghalConn well I wouldn't expect them to help. It's unmanaged hosting...

Comment: Well in that case, go for OVH. I'm currently running my Java based application on their cloud VPS and its great, and its far cheaper than ASO as long as you can manage it... bare in mind it doesnt come with a control panel like ASO does as standard, so you will either need to pay extra, install a free one yourself or manage your website via SSH which is a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

It could any number of things, Slow broadband, Slow host, Slow computer, Slow servers, Bad code,

Its highly unlikely to be the fact that your on shared unless its a very badd host.

I would recommend OVH though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing the page and clearing the cache?

Your browser may be caching it so it doesn't have to keep checking. Hold CTRL when pressing F5 to refresh.

Comment: It's probably still your cache though, clear it however you do on a Mac =]